# Arguing a quantity is a proxy for another

Tags: correlation, modeling

Given the availability of two related metrics $x$ and $y$ for some population (or dataset) $A$, I was looking for a statistical tool to justify replacing $x$ for $y$ in some other population $B$ where the metric $y$ is unavailable.

The procedure that first comes to mind is to establish a strong correlation between $x$ and $y$ using population $A$ data and then use this large correlation coefficient to justify the use of $x$ instead of $y$ in population $B$, since for $B$, metric $y$ remains unavailable.

I was wondering if there was a statistical technique more robust than the correlation coefficient to justify that a metric $x$ can be used as a proxy for another metric $y$ when both $x, y$ are available in an old dataset $A$ but only $x$ is available in the new one $B$.

Comment: Another approach might be to turn this into a prediction problem, predict x and y separately in A, if they return similar errors then it might indicate that they hold similar information.

Comment: @user2974951 thank you for the suggestion, however I think this may not be applicable to my setting since there isn't a model to predict $x, y$ from other information in $A$ and I don't think such a model exists for the kind of data in $A$